# How to use Firestore with paging 3 and RxPagingSource

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, rx-java2, android-paging-3

I am creating an app in which i am using RxJava and paging 3 library.
I am using RxPagingSource and Retrofit to paginate response coming from Server
but i have to fetch some data from Firestore and have to paginate

```
override fun loadSingle(params: LoadParams<QuerySnapshot>): Single<LoadResult<QuerySnapshot, Notification>> {
        var currentPage : QuerySnapshot
        if(params.key != null){
            currentPage = params.key!!
        }else{
            reference
                .limit(10)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener {
                    if(it.isSuccessful){
                        currentPage = it.result
                        val lastDocumentSnapshot = it.result.documents[it.result.size() - 1]
                        reference
                            .limit(10)
                            .startAfter(lastDocumentSnapshot)
                            .get()
                            .addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener {
                                val nextPage: QuerySnapshot
                                if(it.isSuccessful){
                                    nextPage = it.result
                                    return Single.just(
                                        LoadResult.Page(
                                            data = currentPage.toObjects(Notification::class.java),
                                            prevKey = null,
                                            nextKey = nextPage
                                        )
                                    )
                                    //return
                                }
                            })
                    }
                })
        }
```

This is code i tried but its not working for me, there is many mistake in this code

How can i paginate Firestore data using RxPagingSource provided by Paging 3 library

Comment: "it's not working" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect? Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo i followed https://medium.com/@ericampire/firestore-pagination-with-paging-3-762e371cc57f this which is use to paginate by coroutine i modify code given to this link to RxPagingSource but i failed

Comment: You might also be interested in this article, [How to paginate Firestore using Paging 3 on Android?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-paginate-firestore-using-paging-3-on-android-c485acb0a2df). It's not with RxJava, but I think you might get the idea.

Comment: @AlexMamo i know how to paginate Firestore using Paging3 with coroutine , but want it with Rx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PagingDataSource.kt

```
class NotificationPagingDataSource(val service: AppRepository) :
    RxPagingSource<Int, Notification>() {

    override fun loadSingle(params: LoadParams<Int>): Single<LoadResult<Int, Notification>> {

        val page = params.key ?: 1
        return service.getFireNotification(page)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map {
                toLoadResult(it, page)
            }
            .onErrorReturn {
                LoadResult.Error(it)
            }
    }


    private fun toLoadResult(
        data: QuerySnapshot,
        page: Int
    ): LoadResult<Int, Notification> {
     
        Log.i("TAG"," mappingstarted:::  3")
        return LoadResult.Page(
            data = data.toObjects(Notification::class.java),
            prevKey = if (page <= 1) null else page - 1,
            nextKey = if (data.size() == 0) null else page + 1
        )
    }


    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, Notification>): Int? {
        return state.anchorPosition
    }


}
```

AppRepository.kt

```
 var timestamp : String? = null

fun getFireNotification(i: Int): Single<QuerySnapshot> {


        return Single.create<QuerySnapshot>(SingleOnSubscribe { emitter ->

            if (i == 1) {
                FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                    .collection(Constant.NOTIFICATION_NODE).document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser.uid)
                    .collection(Constant.USER_NOTIFICATION_NODE)
                    .limit(15)
                    .get()
                    .addOnCompleteListener {
                        if (it.isSuccessful) {
                            emitter.onSuccess(it.result)
                            timestamp = it.result.documents.last().data?.get("timestamp").toString()
                        }
                    }
                    .addOnFailureListener {
                        Log.i("TAG"," addOnFailureListener:: $it")
                    }
            } else {
                FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                    .collection(Constant.NOTIFICATION_NODE).document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser.uid)
                    .collection(Constant.USER_NOTIFICATION_NODE)
                    .orderBy("timestamp",Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                    .startAfter(timestamp)
                    .limit(15)
                    .get()
                    .addOnCompleteListener {
                        if (it.isSuccessful) {
                            if(it.result.documents.isNotEmpty()) {
                                emitter.onSuccess(it.result)
                                timestamp = it.result.documents.last().data?.get("timestamp").toString()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .addOnFailureListener {
                    }
            }
        })
    }
```

FirebaseViewModel.kt

```
private val notificationPagingdata: MediatorLiveData<PagingData<NotificationModal>> =
        MediatorLiveData()

    fun getNotification(){
         disposable.add(Pager(
            config =  PagingConfig(
                pageSize = 15,
                enablePlaceholders = false,
                prefetchDistance = 1,
            ),
            pagingSourceFactory = {
                NotificationPagingDataSource(repository)
            }
        ).flowable.subscribe({
           notificationPagingdata.value  = it
           }
       )
     )
}

 fun observeNotificationPagingDataSource():LiveData<PagingData<NotificationModal>>{
        return notificationPagingdata
    }
```

YourFragment or Activity.kt

```
private fun setObserver() {
        fireViewModel.observeNotificationPagingDataSource().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            adapter.submitData(lifecycle,it)
        })
    }
```